# Looking for open source icon library

Tags: java, web, icons

For a java project I am working on, I'm looking for a decent open source library of icons to use in the GUI.

I've found several libraries via Google searches, and have not yet found the icon that is 'just right'. I'm interested in any that other developers use, before I start pulling them into my code.

Comment: http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/

Comment: How about [**iconfinder**](http://www.iconfinder.com) with search-filter set to "Allowed for commercial use, No Link required."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Thanks @deceze I did read that first. I'll withdraw my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advise is to try looking at icons for webdesigners, you will get much more results:

- http://www.webdesigncore.com/2012/03/09/20-free-gui-icon-sets-for-web-designers/
- http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/40-free-and-useful-gui-icon-sets-for-web-designers/
- http://ionicons.com

Or obviously the search engines:

- http://www.freeiconsweb.com
- http://www.iconfinder.com/free_icons

Also, you might prefer building **your own font** with vector icons:

- https://icomoon.io

Hope this helps